# Python, not able to get the index working in my list

Tags: python, list, loops, types

I have a list that contains some values as given below:

```
PC1=list();

PC1=[57,49,41,33,25,17,9,1,58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2,59,51,43,35,27,19,11,3,60,52,44,36,63,55,47,39,31,23,15,7,62,54,46,38,30,22,14,6,61,53,45,37,29,21,13,5,28,20,12,4]
```

Thats ok. Now, I do have a string that I enter an "bitsequence" (well, its a sequence of characters 1 and 0...) to:

```
print ("The main key entered is: " + KEY)
#test key that I enter: 0001001100110100010101110111100110011011101111001101111111110001
```

Yepp, thats the first step in DES when initial preparing for creating the 16 subkeys I tries to achieve here. So when using the items in the PC1 list I thought that the corresponding character from my KEY string should be picked, I iterate according to:

```
KEY_PERM = list();

i=0

for i in range(0,56): 
    print ("index", i, "PC1 ", PC1[i], "value from KEY ", KEY[PC1[i]])
    KEY_PERM.insert(i, KEY[PC1[i]])
```

mm, by this the KEY_PERM list that is now populated based upon the PC1 index should be: 11110000110011001010101011110101010101100110011110001111

but.... it is not, it gives me the list:

```
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']
```

And that is incorrect, for instance, the character in place 41 and 33 in the KEY string is not 0....but 1!
11110000110011001010101011110101010101100110011110001111 and not, as now, 0 and 0 as returned characters.

Please help me out! Yepp, I am a total beginner in Python, but wants to learn. I guess that the initial zeroes in the string might be treated wrong? or that the index runs crazy due to me not looping correctly, or something else... like wrong types etc. I dont now.

Comment: please format your question so that it becomes readable.

Comment: There is no error. The character at index 33 in your key as well as at position 41 are both 0

Comment: no, they are 1 in both cases I belive:

Comment: 000100110011010001010111011110011  00110111  01111001101111111110001

I broke up the sequence, the last digit in the first sequence is bit 33 and is a 1 and the last digit in the second sequence is bit 41 and also with value 1.

Comment: I think you have an off by one error. I get both 33 and 41 from your original key are '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused what position 33 means. When not in the context of programming, then you would look at the 33rd entry in your list, which in your case is 1.

In Python and many other languages arrays and lists are indexed, starting at 0. So the 1st entry in your list has index 0. So when you tell python key[33] it actually looks up the **34th** entry in your list. That is 0 as the script also outputs. What you want is the **33rd** entry in the list. Which has index **33-1=32**. So you need to do:

```
for i in range(0,56): 
    print ("index", i, "PC1 ", PC1[i], "value from KEY ", KEY[PC1[i]-1])
    KEY_PERM.insert(i, KEY[PC1[i]-1])
print(''.join(KEY_PERM))
>>> '11110000110011001010101011110101010101100110011110001111'
```

Notice `PC1[i]-1` when using the entry from `PC1[i]` to acces `KEY`

**Complete Test Script**:

```
PC1=[57,49,41,33,25,17,9,1,58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2,59,51,43,35,27,19,11,3,60,52,44,36,63,55,47,39,31,23,15,7,62,54,46,38,30,22,14,6,61,53,45,37,29,21,13,5,28,20,12,4]
KEY='0001001100110100010101110111100110011011101111001101111111110001'
KEY_PERM=[]
for i in range(0,56):
    KEY_PERM.insert(i, KEY[PC1[i]-1])
print(''.join(KEY_PERM))
```

prints: `11110000110011001010101011110101010101100110011110001111`

Comment: Thanks! I will try it directly to see if I will have the expected result.

Nope, that did not solve the problem, it is still the wrong output for KEY_PERM.

Comment: @ler I am getting the correct output for KEY_PERM. What is wrong in yours?

Comment: Hmm, do you get the KEY_PERM list as: 11110000110011001010101011110101010101100110011110001111

??

Comment: @ler what do you get as output?

Comment: ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']

This result is totally wrong. I just took positions 33 and 41 as examples of that it is not working correctly. Yes, I know, the first position is 0, thats not the issue really. Just think of the leftmost as position 1 when counting to pos 33 and 41 in KEY.

Comment: @ler with the code I have now posted I get the reported output. I do not know why you would get something else

Comment: yes, that code works, thanks! I wonder, is it the input of the "key" that could be the error? I will test.

Comment: @ler Try using print(reps(KEY)) to see what actually ends up in your python script

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to understand now why my code was so rubbish as to learn. Have a nice day!

Comment: Good luck. Feel free to accept the answer, so others know the problem to be solve. Also for your answer below, you can click the delete button to delete it

Comment: yepp, I found it.